# Z-Index issue for an item from two different containers

Tags: css, position, z-index, fixed

I'm facing an issue with floated items from different two containers.
One container is header with fixed position and have menu with absolute position. Another container is for the content and its have a action bar with fixed position. The problem is while clicking on the menu item, the action bar overlapping the menu. Please see the fiddle below.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bijusubhash/ymkp2a84/)

```
<div class="floted-header">
  <div class="menu-item">menu item</div>
</div>
<div class="content-scroll">
    <div class="floated-item">
    </div>    
</div>
.floted-header{
    background:red;
    height:100px;  
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    }
 .menu-item{
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    background:gray;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.content-scroll{   
    background:green;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
.floated-item{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    height:50px;
}
```

Please help me to fix this problem. I can't change the action bar html position. Its dynamically changing the action buttons depending on the content.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: .floated-header { z-index: 10; } ?

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index` like

```
.floted-header{ z-index:1;}
```

and

```
.content-scroll{ z-index:0;}
```

[see jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qegc7jpt/)

let me this is what you want or not.